# Evaluating a specific Information retrieval system with P@1

Tags: precision, information-retrieval

I am working on a information retrieval system which aims to select the first result and to link it to other database. Indeed, our system is based on a Keyword description of a video and try to interlink the video to a DBpedia entity which has the same meaning of the description. In the step of evaluation, i noticid that the majority of evaluation set the minimum of the precision cut-off to 5, whereas in our system is not suitable. I am thinking to put an interval [1,5]: (P@1,...P@5).Will it be possible? !! 
Please provide your suggestions and your reference to some notes.. Thanks..

Comment: What is your "information retrieval system"? What are you using? What is the database you are trying to link it to? What are your evaluation sets?

Comment: @Braiam I am linking a DBpedia entity to a video from TRECVID database basing on the description of the video.

Comment: You should edit those details into your question. Ask yourself this: if I didn't know what is wrong, with the information I'm providing can someone help me.

Comment: @Braiam I think that those details are not intersting. I am only asking if it is possible to compute a precision with a cutoff less than 5.

Comment: How can we know if it's possible if we don't know what tools are being used? We need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely calculate P@1 for a retrieval system, if you have truth labels. (In this case, it sounds like they would be [Video, DBPedia] matching pairs generated by humans).

People generally look at this measure for things like Question-Answering or recommendation systems. The only caveat is that you typically wouldn't use it to train a learning to rank system or any other learning system -- it's not "continuous enough" a near miss (best at rank 2) and a total miss (best at rank 4 million) get equivalent scores, so it can be hard to smoothly improve a system by tuning weights in such a case.

For those kinds of tasks, using Mean Reciprocal Rank is pretty common, if you need something tunable. Also NDCG tends to be okay, too, since it has an exponential discounting factor.

But there's nothing in the definition of precision that prevents you from calculating it at rank 1. It may be more correct to describe it as a "success@1" feature, since you're going to get 0/1 or 1/1 as your two options.